# Wordpress issues with wp_enqueue_script

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am trying to enqueue a JavaScript file from a bare bones php file, but I am having trouble actually getting the JavaScript to enqueue. This is the php file.

```
function zdload_javascript(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'java-code',plugins_url('/update-shortcut.js',__FILE__),array('jquery'),'2.1.1',true);}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts','zdload_javascript');
```

It seems like the solution should be quite simple but for the life of me I can't find my error. For reference, the java code creates a hotkey shortcut. Is my error obvious or is there some subtlety I'm missing?

Comment: Are you wanting to load the script in the admin or on user facing side?

Comment: when you say barebones php file... do you mean that wordpress is not loaded?

Comment: No, wordpress is loaded; I just meant it was a VERY small file. I'm trying to load it on the admin facing side.

Answer (score -1):

This is not correct.

`plugins_url('/update-shortcut.js',__FILE__) ;`

Do it this way.

`plugins_url( 'myplugin/js/update-shortcut.js' );`

TRY THIS :

```
function zdload_javascript(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'java-code',plugins_url( 'myplugin/js/update-shortcut.js' ),array('jquery'),'2.1.1',true);
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts','zdload_javascript');
```